# Rails query between two times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app that has a `Checkin` model. I want to find all records that are within a specific time range for the current day. How would I write a `where` to get all records that were created between 12PM and 4:30PM?

Comment: Which database are you using? the functions to get the hour of day will differ. It will be easiest if you'll store the hour/minute of day in addition to the time.

Comment: I'm using postgresql. I'm using the standard `created_at` timestamp column that Rails provides

Answer (score 58, accepted):

@x1a4's answer should be good for you but you can do it in a more readable and shorter way, using a range.

```
 Checkin.where(created_at: Time.parse("12pm")..Time.parse("4:30pm"))
```

It should generate something like:

```
SELECT "checkins".*
FROM "checkins" 
WHERE ("checkins"."created_at" BETWEEN '2012-05-28 12:00:00.000000' AND '2012-05-28 16:30:00.000000')
```

You can change `Time.parse("12pm")` with any other way to create a time.

Answer (score 16):

This looks like it would work, assuming UTC time zone:

```
Record.where('created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', Date.today + 12.hours, Date.today + 16.5.hours)
```

or with a `BETWEEN`:

```
Record.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today + 12.hours, Date.today + 16.5.hours)
```

`BETWEEN` may or not may include the second value in the range. [Postgres includes it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparison.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use below gem to find the records between dates,

This [gem](https://github.com/radar/by_star) quite easy to use and more clear [By star][1]. I'm using this gem and the API is more clear and the documentation is also well explained.

```
Post.between_times(
 Time.zone.now - 3.hours,  # all posts in last 3 hours
 Time.zone.now
)
```

Here you could pass our field also `Post.by_month("January", field: :updated_at)`

Please see the documentation and try it.